# Given $\frac {dF}{dr} = -2GmMr^{-3}$ solve:

Tags: calculus

Given $$\frac {dF}{dr} = -2GmMr^{-3}$$

Suppose that it is known that the Earth attracts an object with a force that decreases at the rate of $2 N/km$ when $r = 20,000km$. How fast does this force change when $r = 10,000km$?

In this problem, do I just plug in the values for $r$?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is analogous to finding points on a line. You have a given value which will determine the equation for you. From the information given, we know that
$$\frac{dF}{dr} = -2$$
when $r = 20000$. This gives you
$$-2 = -2GmM(20000)^{-3}\implies (20000)^3 = GmM$$
From the given information, what can you say when $r=10000$?

Comment: $(10000)^3 = GmM$ so the force changes by half?

Comment: Not quite. That's the value of $GmM$ which is already determined. You want $GmM(10000)^{-3}$

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little bit confused, how is $(10000)^3$ already determined?

Comment: The value of $GMm$ is what you determined from the information given to you. If you know the value of $GMm$, can you find the value of $-GMmr^{-3}$?

Comment: $-(20,000)^3 * (10,000)^3$?

Comment: Almost, $-(20000)^3\times(10000)^{-3}$

Comment: where did you get 2000?

Comment: so how fast does this force change?

Comment: $\frac{dF}{dr}$ evaluated at $r=10000$ is how fast the force changes. What did you just find?

Comment: Ok, I get it, sorry lol

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need your given information to determine the value of the constant $GmM$.  (Note that you are not given the mass of the other object, so even if you look up the value of $G$ and the mass of the earth, you still need to use the given piece of information.)  Then you are correct that you can then plug in $r = 10,000$ to get the desired value of $dF/dr$.

(It's also possible to think of this problem in terms of proportions: $dF / dr$ is inversely proportional to the cube of $r$.)

Comment: So if I were to plug in $10,000$ and $20,000$, I would get:

$\frac {-2GmM}{(20,000)^3}$

and

$\frac {-2GmM}{(10,000)^3}$

correct?